# Click through / application rate on companies with people listed vs companies without people listed?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs

When setting up a company page in Jobs, the "People" section is optional.

> This is not required to publish your page, but we highly recommend you complete this section. You can always come back and add or modify this later. Developers can leave your page and you can remove them at any time.

"Highly recommend", why?

My company has this section blank. What are the benefits of filling this section out and populating it with our development team?

Obviously our goals are to improve recruitment (and quality of candidates). Does having this section populated do that?

Comment: If you were to apply to a job would you not be interested in who you would be working with?

Comment: Sure, but in my experience I meet potential coworkers during the interview stage, not during the "do I apply to this job" stage. Since, SO is highly recommending this, I was hoping for some statistics behind that recommendation.

Answer (score 2):

From a potential applicant's POV, I learn more about a company through its employees and their current and past experience. I do want to know some of the people I'll be working with.

When I look for a job, I spend a lot of time checking the employees' profiles, whether on Stack Overflow, LinkedIn or any other related platform.

So if I were to apply to a job, seeing some "real" people associated with the company's page, will attract me more and will cause me to investigate more on it and on its people.

It's, of course, a huge plus if some profiles belong to users with high reputation, that's something that your company should be proud of, and it will for sure attract more people.